# how to access checked text view in a list view?

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

i have a checked text view inside of a listview and whenever I click an item in the list view a random checked text view will check (not neccessarily the one I pressed) Here is my code

```
lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            final CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView1);

            checkedTextView.toggle();

        }
    });
```

Where lv2 is my list view and checkedTextView1 is my check view inside each listview item. How do I call a specific checkedTextView. Is there an array format that I can call? eg `checkedTextView[1].toggle();`?

Edit here is my adapter

```
public class SpecialAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private int[] colors = new int[] { R.drawable.row_background_grey,
        R.drawable.row_background_white };

public SpecialAdapter2(Context context, int resource, String[] names) {
    super(context, resource, names);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    view.setBackgroundResource(colors[colorPos]);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: you don't want to check the one you check or not?...

Comment: yes I want to check the one I check. But it checks the top one down (doesnt matter where I check its the same pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the code in onItemClick() to:

```
CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView1);
checkedTextView.toggle();
```

The problem is that you are implicitly calling `findViewById()` on *this* - ie. your Activity. Invoking `findViewById()` on your activity will cause it to search through your entire view hierarchy for the first View it can find with the id checkedTextView1. That's not what you want though - you want to find the specific CheckedTextView in the row item that was clicked. Hence the need to invoke `findViewById()` on arg1.

Comment: Hi, I tried the code but it comes up with the same error. If im not mistaken the view is the list activity lv2 while the position is stored as int arg2. So is there a code to reference the item with arg2?

Comment: One thing you may want to do is rename your parameters from arg0, etc to something more meaningful to you. In this case, arg0 is the ListView and arg1 is the View corresponding to the item that was clicked. Are you using a custom Adapter or one that is provided by Android?

Comment: I posted my custom adapter, it is used to alternate the background color of each item.

Comment: I can't see anything in your custom adapter that would be causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
final CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) arg1;
checkedTextView.toggle();
```